# Why is my array appearing empty after appearing to have an element in it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot that randomly shuffles an array of planets and then picks one to hide a bounty on. Then, if a player has that planet role, they can search for the bounty, The problem is whenever I search for the bounty on the planet, it says that the array is empty, but when I shuffle the planets and show the result, the array doesn't appear to be empty.

This is the shuffling code.

```
let coreworlds = [verzan, albregao, corellia, rishi, coruscant, vurdon, wobani]
let coreworldsresult = []

case 'start':
   function shuffle(coreworlds) {
        for (let i = coreworlds.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
          let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
          [coreworlds[i], coreworlds[j]] = [coreworlds[j], coreworlds[i]];
        }
    }for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        shuffle(coreworlds);}

        coreworldsresult.push(coreworlds[1]);
        message.channel.send('A small bounty has been set somewhere in the core worlds. You will have 6 hours to find the bounty.');

    message.channel.send(coreworldsresult);// This always shows the random world.

      setTimeout(() => {
            if(coreworldsresult.lenght != 0){
            coreworldsresult.length = 0
            message.channel.send('Nobody claimed the bounty in time. It`ll take me another 12 hours before I can find another small bounty.')
            }else{
                coreworldsresult.length = 0
                message.channel.send('I`m gonna be getting another small bounty in 12 hours.')
            }
        }, 21600000);
    setInterval(() => {
        function shuffle(coreworlds) {
            for (let i = coreworlds.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
              let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
              [coreworlds[i], coreworlds[j]] = [coreworlds[j], coreworlds[i]];
            }
        }for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            shuffle(coreworlds);}
            coreworldsresult.push(coreworlds[1])
            message.channel.send('A small bounty has been set somewhere in the core worlds. You will have 6 hours to find the bounty.')

            setTimeout(() => {

                if(coreworldsresult.lenght != 0){
                coreworldsresult.length = 0
                message.channel.send('Nobody claimed the bounty in time. It`ll take me another 12 hours before I can find another small bounty.')
                }else{
                    coreworldsresult.length = 0
                    message.channel.send('I`m gonna be getting another small bounty in 12 hours.')
                }
            }, 21600000);


    }, 64800000);
```

This is the searching code.

```
 case 'search':
 message.channel.send('You look around for the bounty.')
message.channel.send(coreworldsresult.length);// This always comes back as "0"

if(member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === coreworldsresult || midrimresult || outerrimresult)){
message.reply('you found a bounty! Now shoot him with `!attack <large, medium, or small>- 
  bounty <weapon>`!')
   }else{
    message.reply('you did not find anything. Try a different planet.')
   }

break;
```

Comment: Fyi, you have a typo in both cases of the line `if(coreworldsresult.lenght != 0){` so it's not going to branch the way you expect. lenght -> length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being a new to programming, one thing I would suggest when getting stuck with unexpected outcomes is to work from the top down and create cases where you **KNOW** what the outcome should be and eventually you'll get down to the part of your code that has either a syntax error or a logical error.

I usually add console logs to all my conditionals when debugging problems.

Comment: Thank you. That helped me identify the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the reason was because my arrays were declared under the

```
client.on('message', message =>{
```

so the changes to them only applied to the code in the same case area. I fixed this by putting the arrays at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Like @EvanMorrison said you have typo in the word length

```
setTimeout(() => {
            if(coreworldsresult.lenght != 0){
```

also please use the DRY principal (Dont't repeat yourself), by wrapping your code in functions and then use them as many time as you need

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful and cleaned everything up a lot.